flutter_facebook_auth does not redirect to my app
I am using flutter_facebook_auth to log into my app.
LoginResult facebookLoginResult = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(
         permissions: ['email', 'public_profile'],
         loginBehavior: LoginBehavior.dialogOnly);

The first time I log into the app from Facebook, it launches Facebook on the web. It verifies by sending a two-factor auth check, then launches Facebook on the web. It never redirects back to my app. If I close the browser, I get a Facebook cancelled status return from my Facebook login call.
The next time I log in with Facebook, it tells me, "You have logged in to this app as X. Do you want to continue?" If I say yes, it logs in via Facebook as expected.
Do you have any idea how to get the initial login once successful in Facebook to redirect back to my app?
This worked in previous versions. I have verified my settings they appear correct, but was there any recent changes I should try?
Just to re-iterate I do not get a response from await FacebookAuth.instance.login until the browser is closed on the initial login.
Here is a link to the documentation: flutter_facebook_auth
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_facebook_auth/flutter_facebook_auth.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

String prettyPrint(Map json) {
  JsonEncoder encoder = const JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ');
  String pretty = encoder.convert(json);
  return pretty;
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Map<String, dynamic>? _userData;
  AccessToken? _accessToken;
  bool _checking = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkIfIsLogged();
  }

  Future<void> _checkIfIsLogged() async {
    final accessToken = await FacebookAuth.instance.accessToken;
    setState(() {
      _checking = false;
    });
    if (accessToken != null) {
      print("is Logged:::: ${prettyPrint(accessToken.toJson())}");
      // now you can call to  FacebookAuth.instance.getUserData();
      final userData = await FacebookAuth.instance.getUserData();
      // final userData = await FacebookAuth.instance.getUserData(fields: "email,birthday,friends,gender,link");
      _accessToken = accessToken;
      setState(() {
        _userData = userData;
      });
    }
  }

  void _printCredentials() {
    print(
      prettyPrint(_accessToken!.toJson()),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _login() async {
    final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(); // by default we request the email and the public profile

    // loginBehavior is only supported for Android devices, for ios it will be ignored
    // final result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(
    //   permissions: ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_birthday', 'user_friends', 'user_gender', 'user_link'],
    //   loginBehavior: LoginBehavior
    //       .DIALOG_ONLY, // (only android) show an authentication dialog instead of redirecting to facebook app
    // );

    if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {
      _accessToken = result.accessToken;
      _printCredentials();
      // get the user data
      // by default we get the userId, email,name and picture
      final userData = await FacebookAuth.instance.getUserData();
      // final userData = await FacebookAuth.instance.getUserData(fields: "email,birthday,friends,gender,link");
      _userData = userData;
    } else {
      print(result.status);
      print(result.message);
    }

    setState(() {
      _checking = false;
    });
  }


  Future<void> _logOut() async {
    await FacebookAuth.instance.logOut();
    _accessToken = null;
    _userData = null;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Facebook Auth Example'),
        ),
        body: _checking
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        _userData != null ? prettyPrint(_userData!) : "NO LOGGED",
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      _accessToken != null
                          ? Text(
                              prettyPrint(_accessToken!.toJson()),
                            )
                          : Container(),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      CupertinoButton(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: Text(
                          _userData != null ? "LOGOUT" : "LOGIN",
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        onPressed: _userData != null ? _logOut : _login,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 50),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

